# how to distribute a database with a REST service

Tags: android, sql, visual-studio-2010, cloud-hosting

I have a small application base on Android. I also have and external DB (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) with service written on Visual Studio 2010. My question is- Haw to distribute my DB and Service for all over the world ? I try with Amazon RDS. But there are only DB, what about my service ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a Serverless architecture!

API Gateway + Lambda Function which will make queries to your database.

Here is a nice starter pack:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-tutorial.html